# Fluentd not forwarding logs to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, fluentd

I have deployed fluentd and elastic search in k8s. If I check the log of the fluentd pod it logs: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product.

My fluentd.conf is:

```
 <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.** >
        @type elasticsearch
        host http://elasticsearch
        port 9200
        logstash_format true
</match>
```

How do I send the docker container logs to elastic search.

Comment: This appears to be a warning, not an error. Have you checked the Elasticsearch instance to see if logs are actually being written there? If they aren't, please update your question with the _exact_ message that you're getting from Fluentd (not your summary of it).

Comment: This is a warning. Just included the parse regEx and worked.